# Area of semialgebraic set

Tags: integration, analysis, polynomials, area, semialgebraic-geometry

Consider the following system of polynomial inequalities with variables $q_1,\ q_2$.

\begin{align*}
a_1 \leq q_1 + q_2 \leq a_2\\
b_1 \leq q_1^2 + q_2^2 \leq b_2\\
c_1 \leq q_1^3 + q_2^3 \leq c_2 \\
0<q_1,\ q_2 <1
\end{align*}
Assume that there exists a feasible solution $(p_1, p_2)$ and let $D$ be the set of solutions of the above system.

I am not sure if this helps but we know that $a_1, a_2, b_1,\ldots$ have 
the following form
\begin{equation}
a_1 = p_1 + p_2 - \epsilon,\ a_2 = p_1 + p_2 + \epsilon \\
b_1 = p_1^2 + p_2^2 - \epsilon,\ b_2 = p_1^2 + p_2^2 + \epsilon \\
c_1 = p_1^3 + p_2^3 - \epsilon,\ c_2 = p_1^3 + p_2^3 + \epsilon
\end{equation}
where $0< \epsilon < 1$.

I know (through experiments) that the feasible set of this system consists of at most $2$ connected components.

**Questions**

> Is there any method to upper bound the **area** of the feasible set $D$ as a function of $a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2, c_1, c_2$ ?
>
> Could it be done analytically using integration ?

Comment: You can do trivial bounds by only considering one of the equations - considering all of them at the same time is going to be fairly difficult because you're going to need to compute all the crossings of each equation with eachother. Where does this problem come from? Maybe there's a better approach (but sometimes you just have to sit down and compute).

Comment: Maybe using the approach of *Henrion, Didier, Jean B. Lasserre, and Carlo Savorgnan* [**Approximate volume and integration for basic semialgebraic sets**](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.2505) , SIAM Rev. 51, No. 4, 722-743 (2009) you can generate a semi-definite program that can be explicitly solved as a function of $a_1$,$a_2$,$b_1$,$b_2$,$c_1$,$c_2$?